# Best way to style a component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have two solutions to style my component. Which one is the better choice?

- First option is to set everything in the styled component.
- Second option is to use many container and styles one by one containers.

First option:

```
export const BaseContainer = styled.div`
  span {
    color: #E0E0E0;  
  }
  i {
     margin-right: 16px;
    }
`;
```

```
<BaseContainer data-testid="base">
   <i className="icon-share" />
   <span> {base} </span>
</BaseContainer>
```

---

Second option:

```
export const BaseContainer = styled.div`
  color: #E0E0E0; 
`;
export const IconContainer = styled.div`
  margin-right: 16px;
`;
```

```
<IconContainer>
  <i className="icon-share" />
</IconContainer>
<BaseContainer data-testid="base">
  {base} 
</BaseContainer>
```

Comment: You should style the elements themselves and not pollute the DOM with excess divs that aren't necessary (so second option but instead of div wrappers just styled the element itself). Also, `styled-components` does some smart things around styling elements, for instance when elements have the same styles it merges these as a single class for performance. You aren't leveraging these useful utilities if you put all of the styling in a parent like your first option. I'd recommend you avoid styling in that manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the **second option** as the first option ties together 2 elements in one div and if you would want to use the same css properties in another case would require refactoring.

But be aware that your second option is not really a small difference from the first:

> - In your first option you have one `div` with one `i` and one `span` inside of it and you are applying style to `i` and `span` correspondingly.
> - In your second option you have 2 separate `div` one with one `i` and the other with just a content and you are applying style to both `div` instead.

That said, the best solution would be to actually style the `span` and `i` individually, something like

```
const StyledSpan = styled.span`
    color: #E0E0E0;
`

const StyledIcon = styled.i`
    margin-right: 16px;
`
```

And then use them as:

```
<div data-testid="base">
  <StyledIcon className="icon-share" />
  <StyledSpan>{base}</StyledSpan>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bit opinion based, but I would approach this a manner like this:

```
const IconContainer = styled.i`
  margin-right:16px;
`;

const Icon = ({ 
    iconType, 
    ...props}) => <IconContainer className={ `icon-${iconType}` } {...props } />;

const BaseContainer = styled.div`
   color: #E0E0E0;
`;

const LabelledIcon = ({ iconType, ...props }) => <BaseContainer>
    <Icon iconType={ iconType } />
   { props.children }
</BaseContainer>;

// usage:
<LabelledIcon iconType="share"> icon label text </LabelledIcon>
```